# innerText solution for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have written a lot of pages last month and today I realized that `innerText` doesn't work in Firefox.
I found `textContent`, but I don't want to dig my tons of pages.
Also sometimes I used `jQuery.text`, it seems to work everywhere.

So question: what is the simplest way out of this hell?

Comment: innerText? please put some code here so that on can answer.if you want to replace html of div use innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the [DOM approach](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementmethods.shtml)?

```
var elem = document.getElementById("ElementID");
var text = document.createTextNode("Text");
text.nodeValue += " and more Text";
elem.appendChild(text);
```

It's not so search-and-replace friendly, but it will guarantee you compatibility across the browsers.

You also may need to remove all the elements from the node if you use this approach.  You can do that like:

```
while ( elem.hasChildNodes() ) {
    elem.removeChild( elem.firstChild );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would never use this in production code but...

```
if ( typeof HTMLElement != 'undefined' && HTMLElement.prototype.__defineGetter__ != 'undefined' ) {
    HTMLElement.prototype.__defineGetter__("innerText", function () {
        return this.textContent;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search and replace `innerText` with the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

Comment: As you said there are not always easy ways out of the hell :-) A decent editor and appropriate regular expression could make this a single click task.